# Group array of item on same value

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Hi I am having array as below:

my array:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 72,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test2",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "green-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 71,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test1",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "red-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    "Id": 70,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test2",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "orange-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

if FolderName is same i want to group into one and add the data of two common folder supportingDocs in supportingDocs array so i want **output like this**:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 72,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test1",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "green-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 71,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test2",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "red-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      },{
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "orange-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

I have tried using indexOf but not working Any solution to group array if foldername is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this. Here's a sample that uses [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {  
  const existing = acc.find(e => e.folderName == curr.folderName);
  if (existing) {
    existing.supportingDocs = existing.supportingDocs.concat(curr.supportingDocs);
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

In my code I also use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Id": 72,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test2",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "green-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 71,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test1",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "red-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    "Id": 70,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test2",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "orange-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {  
  const existing = acc.find(e => e.folderName == curr.folderName);
  if (existing) {
    existing.supportingDocs = existing.supportingDocs.concat(curr.supportingDocs);
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A stupid way:

```js
let origin = [
  {
    "Id": 72,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test2",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "green-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 71,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test1",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "red-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    "Id": 70,
    "PropertyId": 58,
    "folderName": "test2",
    "supportingDocs": [
      {
        "FilePath": "path",
        "FileName": "orange-logo.png",
        "UploadedDate": "2020-04-29T15:00:41.423"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let temp = [];
let output = [];
for( key in origin ) {
  let each = origin[key];
  let folderName = each["folderName"];
  
  if(temp.includes(folderName)){
    // if the foldername already exist.
    for ( i in output ){
      if(getKeyByValue(output[i], folderName) != undefined){
        output[i]["supportingDocs"].push(each["supportingDocs"][0]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // if the foldername not exist    
    temp.push(folderName);
    output.push(each);
  }
}

console.log(output);

// find object key by value, not recursive.
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}
```